# Probability to find a prime lesser than 100 in i-th position of a sequence for n numbers

Tags: probability, algorithms, education

Suppose you implemented a prime number generator to randomly produce a sequence of `n` primes such that only one of them is less than 100. What is the probability of the prime lesser than 100 being in the second position of the sequence?

Comment: This is quite underspecified. What distribution over primes is being used here? How are you guaranteeing that only one of them is less than $100$? Or are you conditioning on that observation?

Comment: I guess the default hypothesis is that the small prime is just as likely to be in the second position as it is to be in the first position, or the last position, or the 17th or 42nd or any other particular position, so the answer should be $1/n$. If that's not right, then there must be something else going on that you aren't telling us about.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I know the answer is ```(n-2)!/(n!)```, but I do not know how to obtain it.

Comment: Sorry, Adee, that makes no sense. You "know" the answer – how do you know this?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The question and the final answer were provided to us, and we were asked to derive it. I tried Bayes conditional probability as well but in vain. Probably, I am not doing it right!

Comment: Then I would go to whomever it was that provided the question and the answer to you, and ask for an explanation. The formula you give says if you have three numbers, and one of them is small, then the probability that the small one is the second one is one-sixth. Does that make sense to you? What is the probability that the small one is the first? What is the probability that the small one is the third? Please put those questions to the one who provided you with the question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ terms to the sequence only $1$ of which we are choosing to pick (the second one, not that this matters). Assuming an equal probability for each position in the sequence then the answer is $\frac1{n \choose 1}=\frac1n$.

This question is equivalent to asking the probability of choosing a red ball from a bag of $1$ red and $n-1$ blue balls. There is nothing special about the elements of the sequence being primes or the position in the list of the prime we look at. Unless of course, we do not have an even probability distribution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).